# How do you detect if a file has a blank line at the end with a BufferedReader?

Tags: java, file-read

I am currently working on a INI file parsing library, but I just have one issue when I am attempting to create a category with a method that I made.

The content of the INI file that I am using is as followed:

```
; Format example
[Category]
key=value

; Just a test to see if setting the same key in a different category
; would mess up the reading, which it didn't.
[Language]
cplusplus=C++
key=java
(No extra line; file ends at "key=java")
```

When I am creating a category with the method, it will attempt to add enough new lines so each category has 1 blank line between the end of the previous category and the one you are creating. If I keep the file as is, which is with no extra blank line at the end of the file, it works fine. But if I change the file content to this:

```
; Format example
[Category]
key=value

; Just a test to see if setting the same key in a different category
; would mess up the reading, which it didn't.
[Language]
cplusplus=C++
key=java

(File has extra line; file ends after the "key=java" line)
```

It creates two empty lines between the two categories... But I don't understand why, as I check if the last line is already blank. I some-what new to Java, so please tell me if I am making some obvious mistake.

```
/**
 * Adds a category to the current INI file.
 * 
 * @param category The category to be added to the file
 */
public void addCategory(String category) {
    if (iniFile == null) return;

    // Checking to see if the file already contains the desired category
    boolean containsCategory = false;
    String lastLine = "";
    String string;

    try (BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(iniFile))) {
        while ( (string = in.readLine()) != null) {
            // Line is a comment or is empty, ignoring
            if (!string.equals(""))
                if (string.charAt(0) == ';' || string.charAt(0) == '#')
                    continue;

            lastLine = string;

            // Line is a category, checking if it is the category that is
            // about to be created
            if (!string.equals("") && string.charAt(0) == '[') {
                String thisCategory = string.substring(1, string.length() - 1);
                if (thisCategory.equals(category))
                    containsCategory = true;
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {}

    // The file does not contain the category, so appeanding it to the end
    // of the file.
    if (!containsCategory) {
        try (BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(iniFile, true))) {
            if (!lastLine.equals("")) {
                System.out.println("Adding extra whitespace");
                out.newLine();
                out.newLine();
            }

            out.write('[' + category + ']');
            out.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {}
    }
}
```

If you want to see the full file source, here is the link to the [GitHub](https://github.com/DealerNextDoor/INIParser/blob/master/src/net/netii/platinumcoding/ini/INIReader.java) that it is uploaded on.

EDIT:

I just thought I should provide what the files look like after I call the `addCategory(String)` method.

After I call `addCategory("Example")` on the first file (No extra blank line):

```
; Format example
[Category]
key=value

; Just a test to see if setting the same key in a different category
; would mess up the reading, which it didn't.
[Language]
cplusplus=C++
key=java

[Example]
```

After I call `addCategory("Example")` on the second file (with an extra blank line at the end of the file):

```
; Format example
[Category]
key=value

; Just a test to see if setting the same key in a different category
; would mess up the reading, which it didn't.
[Language]
cplusplus=C++
key=java


[Example]
```

Comment: Um, because ... appending to an existing file isn't going to magically remove the extra blank line that's in it? You're appending to the file ... that's not going to change the contents that exist prior to what you append.

Comment: @BrianRoach which is exactly what I want it to do. I don't want the line to "magically" be removed, I want an extra line to be created. The desired format that I want is the first file (After I called the method).

Comment: Ok, now I understand where you're confused ... answer coming.

Comment: If anyone cares to see what I did to fix the problem, I have uploaded the change to the GitHub provided in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`lastLine` is going to be empty (`""`) if the last line in the file is nothing more than `\n` (or `\r\n`). `readLine` strips off the end-of-line character(s).

You are only adding whitespace when writing the file if `lastLine` is *not* empty. So ... that's not the problem.

However:

1. You don't account for the last line possibly not having an end-of-line character.
2. Your source file with the "extra" line ... doesn't have the end-of-line character(s) but has a space.

That's the only thing that is going to generate the output you show. When you add two newlines you're adding one to the extra line that was missing it, then creating a second "blank" line; there weren't end-of-line characters.

It's also why adding two newlines to the file that ends in `key=java` only produces one "blank line".

You need to account for this when reading the file. A regex perhaps?

In all honestly, it's simply easier to write the entire file each time. This is what the built in `Properties` object does in java.

Comment: I had to edit this a couple times to get what was in my head to make sense :)

Comment: I think I will just re-write the file every time I add a category to it to avoid any possible problems I will have in the future, too. Thanks for the idea.

Comment: Something I want to add, which is probably just me not have the proper EOF character, regardless of if I have an extra blank line in the file or not, the extra blank line was never read when printing the file content. But what you just said answered why it didn't work; it wasn't adding the proper EOF at the end. I know this because when I create two extra blank lines at the end of the file, then print the file content, it prints only one of those lines.

Comment: Yeah, it's around the whole EOL thing, some combination or another. I was trying to explain it in some way that would make sense, I'm glad you figured it out from my stream of thought.

Comment: Oh I get what you mean. Sometimes I can't explains things at all because I can't decode it from my thought process to proper English, and other times I can explain it with ample details. Luckily, I have worked with people before when I was teaching people the basics of Lua, so I got a lot of different kinds of thought processes.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have something against using the scanner class?

With Scanner you can read the file line by line and then split the resulting string at the =.
If split fails on a line(the resulting String[] is 1 in length), then you know the line is of the incorrect format, if that line has a length of 1 and matches "\n" it is an empty line, if scanner.hasNextLine() == false, EOF.

Comment: I was hoping I wouldn't have to use the Scanner just because I prefer the BufferedReader, but I can try that really quick. I'll let you know if it works.

Comment: I did a simple while loop to print out all the lines of the files, which worked, but regardless of whether or not I add the extra blank line at the end of the file, it doesn't print in the while loop. So, I tried to just check with `scanner.hasNextLine()` (both with and without the blank line at the end), and it results in false both times.

Comment: Instead of printing the character, try checking if the string =="\n", it may be that your experiencing the dreaded line eneding issues.

Comment: Do you mean printing it via `Scanner#nextLine()`? Because when I try that, it throws a `NoSuchElementException`.

Comment: No you read each line into a string declared outside the loop, so you can look at the last line and see if it is "\n" after the loop terminates.